# Did Call feature change in iOS 8.4?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have an app that lets users dial a call. Basically it has number input that user enters and then it dials the number using this code.

```
        if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) 
        {
            //its iphone
            NSString *tmpStr1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel://%@", labelStr.text];
            NSLog(@"tmpStr1: %@ ...", tmpStr1);
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:tmpStr1]];
        }
tmpStr1: tel://8003310500 ...
```

Recently I submitted an app update to Apple and I keep getting rejections from the Apple reviewer saying that nothing happens when the call button is pushed.

I tested this on my actual device, iPhone 6 running iOS 8 and it works just fine. My question is, did Apple change something in iOS 8.4 to disable this feature? Is there some sort of user permission needed before doing that? Unfortunately I cannot upgrade my device to iOS 8.4 at this time. (there are some personal reasons)

Comment: Did you test with spaces in the entered number?

Comment: In any case, I think your code should at leat check the return value (boolean) of `-[UIApplication openURL:]`, and do some basic error handling...

Comment: I am stripping out all the spaces, - or () from the number in case user entered those. I just don't know what apple reviewer is using as tel number.

Comment: The # and * symbols are also blocked. You should display an error if the user-entered phone number contains any of those. In fact, why not strip all non-numeric characters? And as others say, you should check that openURL returns TRUE.